# Bar graph of several variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to make a bar chart that shows drug use for multiple variables for drug use: marijuana, cocaine, crack, meth, heroine, hallucinogens, inhalants, pain relievers, and stimulants. I initially recoded the data into factors in a larger data set to show whether they have used the drug before (Yes/No) or recoded to NA. I need to have the drugs along the x axis and county level on the y (urban, peri urban, rural). I don't understand how to select multiple variables to into the x axis.

The initial data is here: https://www.datafiles.samhsa.gov/dataset/national-survey-drug-use-and-health-2020-nsduh-2020-ds0001

I have tried a few things:

1. Make a new data frame. But from here I still have to select which variable I want in ggplot.
   Code:

```
druguse1<-data1.cleaned%>%
  select("MJEVER", "COCEVER","CRKEVER", "HEREVER", "HALLUCEVR",
         "METHAMEVR", "INHALEVER", "PNRNMLIF", "STMANYLIF")
```

2. I think I also tried `filter`, but it took all of the answers and combined them into either "Yes" "No" or "NA", so I couldn't link the data to specific drugs.

Here is a snapshot of the data:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To plot multiple variables along the x axis, you have to `pivot` the data to combine them into one variable.

To attempt a bit of an example (with a quick try at the data - not cleaned), you would `pivot_longer` the Yes/No data, then summarise for example what percentage answered "Yes":

```r
library(tidyverse)

NSDUH_2020 |> 
  as_tibble() |> 
  select(mjever, cocever, crkever, herever,
         hallucevr, methamevr, 
         inhalever, pnrnmlif, stmanylif,
         COUTYP4) |> 
  mutate(across(
    -COUTYP4,
    .fns = factor,
    levels = 1:2,
    labels = c("Yes", "No")
  ),
  COUTYP4 = factor(COUTYP4, labels = c("Large Metro", "Small Metro", "Non Metro"))) |>
  pivot_longer(mjever:stmanylif, names_to = "drug", values_to = "taken") |>
  group_by(drug, COUTYP4) |>
  summarise(taken = sum(taken == "Yes", na.rm = TRUE) / n()) |>
  ggplot(aes(drug, y = taken)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  facet_wrap( ~ COUTYP4, ncol = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful and worked for me. How would I also pull out data by county? Ideally I'd like to see each drug broken into urban/peri urban/rural as well.

Comment: Have redrawn using `COUTYP4` above for example above you can facet by county type. Secret again is to get a column detailing the county of each observation and use that to `facet_wrap` the `ggplot` output!